# PHP CSV Insert using prepared statement

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to insert CSV data into database, i have tried this below

```
<?php 
    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO test (field1, field2, load_time) VALUES (:val1, :val2, sysdate)');
    $i=0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source)) !== FALSE) {  
        if($i!=0) {
            $field1=$data[0];
            $field2=$data[1];
            $stmt->bindParam(':val1', $field1);
            $stmt->bindParam(':val2', $field2);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

this code is not working, please help to fix if any issues in this code, as im new to prepared statement and PDO.

Comment: You are binding twice val1 and zero times val2

Comment: @jeprubio, Hi, thanks,  even i tried $stmt->bindParam(':val1', $field1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':val2', $field2);  it doesnt work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @dops, i get ORA-01861: literal does not match format string, the line it shows is PDOStatement->execute(), i dont have any data type issues, as the fields in table and CSV are varchars.

Comment: If this is the complete code, then $con hasn't been defined.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, yea connection is working fine.

Comment: can you show the description of table test?

Comment: i just removed the timestamp column from table and uploaded. it worked.

Comment: @jeprubio  that would beat the purpose of the prepare: executing the same statement without having to parse it each time.

Comment: Were you trying to put sysdate into a timestamp column?  Perhaps systimestamp would have been a better idea.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, thanks for that, i will try that and update you. but usually when inserting a single row i used sysdate for timestamp column and it worked.

Comment: I would have liked to see the description of the test table, to find an explanation for the ORA-01861.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille,field1         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200)  
field2        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200)        
load_time  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: You should have added the error in the question - not as a comment later. You should be checking for errors on any I/O (fgetcsv and stmt->execute). If you added the error checking then you would be able to see what values you are passing to the statement and include these along with the table definition and any applicable constraints in your quetion.

Comment: @davidb I think this is the solution you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241870/getting-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-on-sqlplus-only

Comment: @dops, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something similar, just one record, inserting sysdate in a timestamp column, but it ran without problem.

```
<?php
  $con = oci_connect(
     "admdba","admdba",
     "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ghp-amdphIIX4B.ghp.be)"
     . "(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=GHPORA)(SID=GHPORA)))");
  if ($con) {
    $stmt = oci_parse(
       $con,
       'INSERT INTO test (field1, field2, load_time)'
       . ' VALUES (:val1, :val2, sysdate)');
    $field1='amehoela';
    $field2='broodkorst';
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':val1', $field1);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':val2', $field2);
    oci_execute($stmt);
    print "Access registered<BR/>";
  } else {
    print "Failed to connect <BR/>";
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
  }
?>
```

One more thing: there are no triggers on your table?

Comment: thank you for your time and efforts, it helped a lot